# When the user click on Locates the retail store for example can I extract coordinates Depending on google map app for example?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am working on Consumer Price Index project and I will implement the project by HTML5 and after that I will use PhoneGap.com tool to convert the HTml5 pages to four platforms(android, ios, windows phone and BlackBerry). the mobile application has a lot of services such as add products, update prices, locates the retail store and read the barcode by using barcode reader app.

The question is :

when the user click on Locates the retail store for example can I extract coordinates Depending on google map app for example ? How?

and also

when the user click on Read the barcode by using barcode reader application for example can I extract the barcode number Depending on any barcode reader application? How?

Comment: I've fixed the title of your question to correctly reflect what you are actually asking.

Comment: U can make use of geolocation plugin